# Azure .NET Core Web API 1.0.1 500 error

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I just upgraded my .NET Core MVC WebAPI application from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1.  Tested locally and it works.  When deployed to Azure, I get the 500 error when trying to invoke any RESTful service.  I turned on logging and anything that could be turned on for diagnostics on Azure.  However I keep getting the generic 500 error message with no detail.  Not sure how to debug this.  Note that .net core 1.0.0 worked just fine for me on Azure.

Comment: BTW, I don't think Azure has this running properly since when I sent a request to one of my services using a content-type other than application/json, I would expect to get a 415 error (Unsupported Media Type).  However I only get a 500 error.  This tells me that none of my Web API services are available.

Answer (score 1):

I've run on the similar issue and found out that Azure was running old version of my app. Reading through [asp.net core github issue #267](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/267) revealed that my issue was that after upgrading to 1.0.1 I had to add runtime section to `project.json`. As user **jamesabolton** wrote:

> To avoid adding runtimes section using 1.0.1 change
> `"Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.0.1"`
> to
> `"Microsoft.NETCore.App": { "version": "1.0.1", "type": "platform" }`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Nice answer. Can you quote the relevant sections from your linked GitHub issue to your answer? Just in case the link dies in the future.